# Unable to references images in a WPF application from a .Net 6 dll

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, migration, .net-6.0

We are migrating our WPF app from .Net 4.7.2 to .Net 6.
Most of our application is in WPF, but we have a project in development that will be in Asp.Net.

Our WPF projects have the `net6.0-windows` target framework. Our non-wpf specific projects have a `net6.0` target framework.

We are referencing images like this:

```
pack://application:,,,/Project.Name;component/Path/Inside/Project/Image.svg
```

We noticed we have an issue, the images doesn't appear in our .Net 6 app.
We noticed that IF we change the "non-WPF-specific" DLL to use also the `net6.0-windows` framework and set the `UseWpf` properties of their project to `true`, it work.

Unfortunately it is not acceptable for us, since we will have to use those project in the Asp.Net core application(in a docker container). I know we have the solution to extract the images in a dedicated project, but currently they are grouped by "package" according to their business object.

Is their a way to avoid to have to make those DLL windows specific or extract all the images and change their path(easily 700+ images to change, from a lot of different projects).

**Note**

- We noticed by decompiling that the images were stripped from the DLL if not having those attributes
- We found other [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/362848/can39t-find-embeded-resources-image-in-net5-wpf-ap.html)([and other people thinking its a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2258)) of people with this issue

Comment: *Is their a way to avoid to have to make those DLL windows specific or extract all the images ... ?* Apparently not. You need to use the Windows SDK to include the image resources.

Comment: @mm8 So basically, it means that it's now 100% IMPOSSIBLE to have an ASP.Net Core(MVC) and a WPF app sharing the same SVG? Not saying it's a good idea, just to be sure.

Comment: Well, you cannot reference the SVG resource using a pack URI at least.

Comment: @mm8 is there another way to reference them?

Comment: You could either copy the files as content to the output directory or trying to extract the embedded resources programmatically.